# could't get the dual sim numbers from mobile_number.dart

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

why i can't able to fetch both the mobile numbers from the device using mobile_number.dart in flutter projects, with the help of the documation code from the mobile_number.dart library i got mobile number of the 1st slot sim card number with the below code.

```
`import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:mobile_number/mobile_number.dart';

void main() => runApp(LoginScreen());

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  String _mobileNumber = '';
  List<SimCard> _simCard = <SimCard>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    MobileNumber.listenPhonePermission((isPermissionGranted) {
      if (isPermissionGranted) {
        initMobileNumberState();
      } else {}
    });

    initMobileNumberState();
  }
  Future<void> initMobileNumberState() async {
    if (!await MobileNumber.hasPhonePermission) {
      await MobileNumber.requestPhonePermission;
      return;
    }
    try {
      _mobileNumber = (await MobileNumber.mobileNumber)!;
      _simCard = (await MobileNumber.getSimCards)!;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Failed to get mobile number because of '${e.message}'");
    }
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {});
  }

  Widget fillCards() {
    List<Widget> widgets = _simCard
        .map((SimCard sim) => Text(
            'Sim Card Number: (${sim.countryPhonePrefix}) - ${sim.number}\nCarrier Name: ${sim.carrierName}\nCountry Iso: ${sim.countryIso}\nDisplay Name: ${sim.displayName}\nSim Slot Index: ${sim.slotIndex}\n\n'))
        .toList();
    return Column(children: widgets);
  }`
```

Comment: There is a similar question which has answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090844/flutter-get-the-phone-number